# itext API Not able to get the fields from Adobe lifecycle tool generated Dynamic pdf

Tags: java, itext, adobe, dynamicpdf

I could see the empty fields all the time with iText, but I can see them when I open using manually using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC

```
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader(
                            new PRInputStream(dataFile));
com.lowagie.text.pdf.AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
System.out.println("Field Names:" + af.getFields());
```

With Static PDF generated by the same software is working fine.

```
Expected records : 1
Actual : 0
```

Please find the sample PDF file
https://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2051245-11361/ExpandingTextBox.pdf

With the below snippet

```
com.lowagie.text.pdf.AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
System.out.println("Field Names:"+af.getXfa().getTemplateSom().getName2Node().toString());
```

I could see 
`Field Names:{form1[0].#subform[0].TextFieldContainer[0].TextField1[0]=[field: null]}` 
but not the actual field names.

Comment: You are working with iText 2.1.7 or older, which is 9 years old. Can you reproduce this with either iText 5.1.3 or 7.1.1, which were released one month ago?

Comment: The issue is that you're trying to read out an XFA form using AcroForm API calls. You're on the right track by getting the XFA form out of the PDF, however, you'll need to parse the XML you've extracted, that's not something iText will do for you.

Comment: @MichaëlDemey sorry i didn't get your point can you please elaborate? my requirement is just to get the available field names from the PDF. you mean iText API wouldn't able to get the field names from Dynamic PDF?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse i have tried with 5.3.4 still the same result for the above snippet, do i need to try with different mthods?

Comment: I asked you to do it with 5.5.13, not with 5.3.4.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse i have tried with 5.5.13 and 7.1.1 still i am getting teh same result, do i need to try with different methods?

Comment: *"I could see ... but not the actual field names."* - Why do you think so? That name matches the structure in the XFA in your PDF... That being said, don't count on iText improving XFA support beyond what you see in 5.5.13 and 7.1.1. XFA forms after all have been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your extended help, i could see the valid field names by iterating through the node multiple times, Please find the below below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is able to extract the field names from the form.

```
    String fieldName = form.getXfa().getDatasetsNode().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getLocalName();
    String str = form.getXfa().getDatasetsNode().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getTextContent();
    String SiblingName = form.getXfa().getDatasetsNode().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNextSibling().getLocalName();
    String SiblingValue = form.getXfa().getDatasetsNode().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNextSibling().getTextContent();
    System.out.println("Field Name:"+fieldName);
    System.out.println("Field Value:"+str);
    System.out.println("Sibling Name:"+SiblingName);
    System.out.println("Sibling Value:"+SiblingValue);
    //Set the values back to form
    form.getXfa().getDatasetsNode().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().setTextContent("Updated: Content for First Field");
    String updatedValue = form.getXfa().getDatasetsNode().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getTextContent();
    System.out.println("Field Value:"+updatedValue);
```

and we could see the correct field and values and i could set the values back to the form didn't try to generate the form back however that would work.

and this usecase worked with all versions of itext (worked with 2.1.7 also)

Comment: i could extract the output something like below.                           
Field Name:TextField1
Field Value:First Field Value
Sibling Name:TextField2
Sibling Value:Second Field Value
Field Value:Updated: Content for First Field